# Selenium-webdriver/Javascript: How do I scroll through a page?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the Javascript API to selenium-webdriver and I would like to scroll/move down through a page *slowly* to allow for visual inspection.

I know the following will jump me to a link at the end of my page:

```
  return driver.findElement({linkText: 'All rights reserved'}).click()
```

However, I'd like to review the stuff in between, as I watch selenium do its thing.

Is it possible to scroll incrementally through a page? (e.g. 10%, 20%, 30% etc.). Or is there another technique to effectively do a "slow scroll"?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two ways-
1.Scroll the page in slow motion-
you can change time in Thread.sleep as per requirement.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
for (int i = 0;; i++) 
{
    if(i >=60)
    {
            break;
        }
 js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)", ""); //800 is Y coordinate. This can be changed
     Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

2.Scroll to element position before performing operation on it-

```
Point p = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value")).getLocation();//get element position
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+(p.getY())+");");
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I've just got to figure it out in Javascript! ;-)